# Subroutine giving two different outputs when called twice

Tags: perl

I have executed the following piece of a simple nested subroutine and the output of it makes me crazy.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;

sub outer {

   my $a = "123";

   sub inner {
      print "$a\n";
   }

   inner();

   $a = "456";
}

outer();
outer();
```

Output to this is

```
Variable "$a" will not stay shared at E:\Perl\source\public\sss.pl line 9.
123
456
```

But how is this possible?

I call the `inner` subroutine when `$a` value is `123`, but why am I getting `456` when outer is called the second time.

Comment: when I change $a declaration to our from my then I get output as 123 123

Comment: Side note: Don't call your variables `$a` or `$b`. Perl uses those names in [`sort`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html).

Comment: I'd also suggest declaring a sub within a sub is rarely a good idea.

Comment: This is going to sound cryptic and weird, but remember that the implications of 'my' come in two parts: the lexical scoping implications are resolved at compile-time; the initialisation assignment happens at run-time. Think about these two parts and what happens each time the statements are executed.

Comment: Erm, because the first call sets `$a` to 456? What is the puzzle here?

Answer (score 4):

`perldoc diagnostics` gives quite self explanatory description for the warning `Variable "$a" will not stay shared`,

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

sub outer {
   my $a = "123";
   sub inner {
      print "$a\n";
   }
   inner();
   $a = "456";
}

outer();
outer();
```

output

> Variable "$a" will not stay shared at -e line 9 (#1)
>
> ```
>    (W closure) An inner (nested) named subroutine is referencing a
>     lexical variable defined in an outer named subroutine.
>
>    When the inner subroutine is called, it will see the value of
>     the outer subroutine's variable as it was before and during the *first*
>     call to the outer subroutine; in this case, after the first call to the
>     outer subroutine is complete, the inner and outer subroutines will no
>     longer share a common value for the variable.  In other words, the
>     variable will no longer be shared.
>
>    This problem can usually be solved by making the inner subroutine
>     anonymous, using the sub {} syntax.  When inner anonymous subs that
>     reference variables in outer subroutines are created, they
>     are automatically rebound to the current values of such variables.
> ```

```
123
456
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no point in declaring an subroutine within another one. It works as if it were declared at the top level, and won't function properly as a closure

If you enable *lexical subroutines* (and disable the corresponding "experimental" warning) and declare `inner` as `my sub inner` then your code will work as you expect

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'lexical_subs';
no warnings 'experimental::lexical_subs';

sub outer {

   my $a = "123";

   my sub inner {
      print "$a\n";
   }

   inner();

   $a = "456";
}

outer();
outer();
```

#### output

```
123
123
```